# Update in laravel don't work in users table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a update in the users table generated by the laravel, i receive the response json status 200 but the data don't change. I try:

```
Route::put('alteraDadosPerfil/{id}', 'Auth\LoginController@alteraDadosPerfil');

function alteraDadosPerfil(Request $request, $id){

     User::findOrFail($id)->first()->fill($request->all())->save();
     return response()->json('Dados de perfil alterados com sucesso', 200);
}
```

I have to make something more to update the data in the users table?

Comment: What does your model look like? Do you have the `$fillable` property set properly?

Comment: Please clarify how You send request from clientside

Answer (score 2):

Use the `update()` method:

```
function alteraDadosPerfil(Request $request, $id){

     User::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
     return response()->json('Dados de perfil alterados com sucesso', 200);
}
```

You don't need to use the `first()` method in this case, the `findOrFail()` method returns a single User.

Also, make sure you put all the fields in the `$fillable` variable in your model:

```
$fillable = ['id', etc...]
```

Answer (score 0):

the `findOrFail()` method returns a single model, and the "first" is used for colletions...

Try changing from:

```
User::findOrFail($id)->first()->fill($request->all())->save();
```

To:

```
User::findOrFail($id)->fill($request->all())->save();
```

Comment: I receive the json success message but the data don't change. I have to do something in jwt?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like You've JSON body, so You've to decode it from raw content:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
User::findOrFail($id)->update($data);
```

or use this:

```
User::findOrFail($id)
      ->update(
        $request->all() // or $request->json()->all()
      );
```

P.S. Make sure You've defined `$fillable` in model.

Also check network tab in browser's inspector to see what browser sends to Your route.

Comment: Where are you getting that they are *sending* JSON in the request? Also even if they are, as long as they are sending the content type properly `$request->all()` will return the decoded object. No `json_decode` nor `->json()` call required.

Comment: @jfadich logic (: 1. since he uses put request to send payload which does not affect on data, 2. since json response being returned (if it was simple form with put then he would not respond with json).   latest laravel supports json body as `request->all()` but in question we don't know which version of laravel he uses.